# Perform calculations using n and nmiss values

Tags: sas

I have the following SAS PROC MEANS statement that works great as it is.

```
proc means data=MBA_NODUP_APPLICANT_&TERM. missing nmiss n mean median p10 p90 fw = 8;
    where ENR = 1;
    by SRC_TYPE;
    var gmattotal greverb2 grequant2 greanwrt;
run;
```

However, I am trying to add new variable calculating nmiss/(nmiss+n).  I don't see any examples of this online, but also nothing that says that it cannot be done.

Comment: Here's a snapshot of what I am trying to accomplish

Variable         N Miss N % of missing observations -- (Nmiss/(Nmiss + N))*100
GMATTOTAL 93         1 98.93617021
GREVERB2 89         5 94.68085106
GREQUANT2 89         5 94.68085106
GREANWRT 88         6 93.61702128

Comment: Using `output` statment to out the result of `proc means` as a dataset, and do calculation as your wish.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the percent missing, which is what your formula means, just use the OUTPUT statement to generate a dataset with the NMISS and N values.  Then add a step to do the arithmetic yourself.

Or you could create a new binary variable using the MISSING() function and take the MEAN of that.  The mean of a 1/0 variable is the same are the percent that were 1 (TRUE).

Example:

```
data test;
 set sashelp.cars;
 missing_cylinders=missing(cylinders);
run;

proc means data=test nmiss n mean;
  var cylinders missing_cylinders ;
run;
```

So 2/428 is a little less than 0.5%.

```
The MEANS Procedure

                        N
Variable             Miss      N            Mean
------------------------------------------------
Cylinders               2    426       5.8075117
missing_cylinders       0    428       0.0046729
```